# Django: Moving 'oscar' site-package

Tags: python, django, django-oscar, site-packages

I am starting my own `Django-Oscar` project, and am wondering about the possibility of changing the location of the `'oscar'-directory` (containing all `apps`, a `models.py` etc), moving it from the default on-installation `site-packages` directory within my `virtual environment` - into my `project root directory.`

Would it be possible to simply copy the `'oscar'-directory`, and paste it into a new location, assuming I also change the locations of the `'INSTALLED_APPS'`, and make sure that my `project-structure` is the same (i.e. not changing things like the `directory-name 'oscar'` so that `imports` etc break)? If so, would that mean that I could delete it all together from `site-packages` (DRY-solution)?

This would mimic the `sandbox-installation`, and would be a set up I'd feel more comfortable with as a beginner who needs visible overhead.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Although, it's not recommended, because then it'd be harder for you to incorporate latest oscar changes into your project, and it's not the recommended way to customize / extend oscar functionality.

Instead of deleting oscar from `site-packages` you should rather `pip uninstall django-oscar`.

Also, it's possible to have oscar installed, as well as copied into your project directory at the same time. By Python defaults, the one in your project directory would be the one that will get imported (instead of the installed). This way, you can have the comfort of working with it locally. I sometimes do this so that I can safely test certain django apps (like oscar) with minor changes (in development environment), but not having to commit / push these changes into a production environment mostly because it's easier this way than following recommended methods to extend the app.

Comment: In my case, I will work be extending a lot of Oscar's functionality over several months, and the recommended way of customisation just does not cover that. What do you think of re-installing django-oscar using editable/developer mode - 'pip install -e path/name/'? Would that be something to consider?

Comment: No, like I said, in your case, just copy the folder into your project. That is the most comfortable and safe method. If you want to include future updates from the original source, just use something like `meld` to compare changes within your directory and the original source's directory.

Comment: Also, you need to note that oscar is popular because it is highly extensible. You could maintain your separate repo for oscar and make changes in that, and use that repo instead of original pip, in your production environment.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback! Thank you a lot. Though, would I be wrong to say that this is not too far off the recommended way of forking/extending an app in the docs? The only real differences in this case, since I took your advice on not deleting the Oscar-site-package, is the fact that I ‘override’ everything - and also copy/extend a few additional files (Oscar.models, context processors...)? I may be wrong here, but it’s the way it seems to me as a beginner!

Comment: It would be wrong to say that. Benefits of forking the app are mentioned in the docs - [classes-are-loaded-dynamically](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/internals/design-decisions.html#classes-are-loaded-dynamically) and [why so](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/topics/class_loading_explained.html#why). In short, it's mostly to avoid duplication, ease of maintenance and upgrading with latest changes.